# wp option get blogname --url=my-sub-site.com returning main site option

Tags: multisite, options, wp-cli

I have a multisite setup with some 14 woocommerce sites.

```
site_id | domain
1       | local.mainsite.com
2       | local.subsite-2.com
3       | local.subsite-3.com
4       | local.subsite-4.com
```

I want to retrieve the blogname of subsite 4 (local.subsite-4.com which exists as a working site, and is also present in wp_blogs).

So, I do: `wp option get blogname --url=local.subsite-4.com`.

It returns the blogname of site 1 (local.mainsite.com, not the subsite set in the --url parameter).

Can anyone reproduce this or have any suggestion on what I am doing wrong here?

I'm using the latest wordpress core.

```
OS: Darwin 20.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0: Sat May  8 05:10:33 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.121.3~9/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/zsh
PHP binary: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.23/bin/php
PHP version:    7.4.23
php.ini used:   /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
MySQL binary:   /usr/local/bin/mysql
MySQL version:  mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.4-MariaDB, for osx10.16 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
SQL modes:  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /Users/jurgen/Sites/local.gasveerwinkel.nl/www
WP-CLI packages dir:    /Users/jurgen/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.5.0
```

Comment: should `globname` be `blogname`? I could not reproduce this locally

Comment: If it returns the blogname of the main site, then it's possible that you made a typo in the `--url` value.. like `--url=local.subste-4.com` (note it's missing the letter "i")? And I actually reproduced the issue by deliberately using a non-existent site. Have you tried using a full URL like `http://local.subsite-4.com` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ I copied the domain directly from the database table wp_blogs. Tried the same with one of the blogs listed with `wp site list`.  I've tried the full url, also the domain without protocol, but with no effect

Comment: So all the other sites but the main one, gave you the main site's blogname? That's strange  and shouldn't happen, so maybe you can try deactivating plugins and/or switching to a default theme? Just in case..

Comment: @SallyCJ All sites return the main site's blogname. I am now doing some tests with disabling plugins and themes, that takes some time with a multisite setup with 14 sites

Comment: Lol sorry, I should've said "gave you the wrong blogname"..  Anyway, you could also try the `--debug` option: `wp option get blogname --url=local.subsite-4.com --debug` - the debug messages might help.